# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на инлайн кнопку в боте, выводился текст в новом сообщении?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Создал две кнопки и привязал их к сообщению, но всё никак не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы к примеру при нажатии кнопки "Профиль", бот отправлял новое сообщение с текстом.

Вот код существующих кнопок:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

startk = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
profil = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='Привет')
contacs = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Контакты', callback_data='Привет')
startk.add(profil, contacs)
```

Comment: с каким текстом? для начала изучите, что означает `callback_data`

Comment: @ZxNuClear, я просто сделал callback_data, чтобы ошибку не выдавало. Я хочу, чтобы он при нажатии на кнопку "Профиль", отправлял новое сообщение, в котором будет вся информация про него, просто подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы он отправлял какое-либо сообщение после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: ну так вы и пишите в `callback_data` не `что попало, лишь бы ошибку не выдавало`, а что то осмысленное и далее пишите обработчик для этих колбэков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно примерно так сделать:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery

startk = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
profil = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='profile')
contacs = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Контакты', callback_data='contacts')
startk.add(profil, contacs)



@dp.callback_query(F.data == "profile")
async def send_profile(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer("Тут некий текст")
```

В `callback_data` пишем то, что будем отлавливать хендлером. Это может быть просто слово, как в пример. А можем передавать и несколько значений, необходимых для обработки запроса